# List.js how to reset sorting to initial state

Tags: javascript, list, sorting, reset, list.js

I'm currently working with the list.js library and its sorting method. The functionality works perfectly when you want to sort `asc` or `desc`, but is there a way to reset everything to initial state from before sorting?

Let's say we have a table with two columns: names and dates of born. When we trigger sorting by clicking the button list.js sorts the column `asc` and on a second click sorts the columns`desc`. So I can toggle between `asc` and `desc`.

I was searching in the docs https://listjs.com/ if there is a method to reset the sorting but didn't find anything.

Here is the quick example of HTML table:

```
<div id="users">
  <table>
    <tbody class="list">
      <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
        Sort by name
      </button>
      <button class="reset" data-sort="born">Reset?</button>
      <button class="sort" data-sort="born">
        Sort by date
      </button>
      <button class="reset" data-sort="born">Reset?</button>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jonny Stromberg </td>
        <td class="born">1986</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jonas Arnklint</td>
        <td class="born">1985</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Martina Elm</td>
        <td class="born">1986</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</td>
        <td class="born">1983</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
```

And the JS:

```
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ]
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
```

So by clicking on sort buttons I can toggle between `asc` and `desc`, but I'm confused how can I reset the sorting using List.js, and back to "initial state" of table.

Working exmple:

```js
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ]
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
```

```html
<div id="users">
  <table>
    <tbody class="list">
      <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
        Sort by name
      </button>
      <button class="reset" data-sort="born">X</button>
      <button class="sort" data-sort="born">
        Sort by date
      </button>
      <button class="reset" data-sort="born">X</button>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jonny Stromberg </td>
        <td class="born">1986</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jonas Arnklint</td>
        <td class="born">1985</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Martina Elm</td>
        <td class="born">1986</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</td>
        <td class="born">1983</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to unset/reset the sort to the initial state?

Comment: Unfortunetely no

Comment: There seems to be no built-in way to do this.
You could manipulate the data to create a default order column/value which can be invisible to the user, and use it to restore the sorted list to the 'initial' state.
Writing a custom sort function might also be useful for some, more info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486659/multiple-sort-in-list-js